# initialization of vectors of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

i am trying the following code segment

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct mytype
{
    int a;
    string b;
};

int main()
{
    vector<mytype*> my_vec(100);
    for (int i =0;i < 200; i++ )
    {
        if (my_vec[i] == NULL)
            printf("%d th Vector is NULL \n",i);
        else
           printf("You are screwed \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i compiled and tried running it, all the 200 vectors were null except the 101st location which was not NULL . May i know why this happened ?
I want to initialize all my vectors to NULL before using it

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code: You make a vector containing 100 entries, and then you step through *200* entries.

Answer (score 2):

You have a vector with 100 elements in it, accessing the 101st location invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The vector's got 100 elements:

```
vector<mytype*> my_vec(100);
//                     ^^^
```

You iterated 100 elements too far:

```
for (int i =0;i < 200; i++ )
//                ^^^
```

Accessing the vector out of bounds is undefined behaviour. Any value is possible and your program may behave however it wants.